# control margin size knitr when producing word document

Tags: r, latex, knitr, r-markdown

I would like to reduce the margin size in word documents produced by knitr.

I have tried two approaches in the YAML header:

```
title: mytitle
author: me
geometry: margin=1cm
output: word_document
```

and also by manually altering the margin in the docx and saving as a template:

```
title: mytitle
author: me
output: word_document
reference_docx: template.docx
```

neither approaches have even slightly altered the margin.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`yaml` seems to be finicky about formatting to explicitly show hierarchies of options. This worked when I tested it on my computer and is [documented here](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/word_document_format.html#style_reference):

```
---
title: mytitle
author: me
output: 
  word_document:
    reference_docx: template.docx
---
```